# The program refuses to enter into the for loop

Tags: c, loops

I am now working on a Binary Search Tree and for some reason, this loop wouldn't even start. We have tried various methods to test whether it's the problem of strlen() or even the data type issue.

ElementType is char*.

```
void sortinsert(Node **root, ElementType str)
{
    int i, j;
    char temp;
    char copy[100];
    strcpy(copy, str);

    int k = strlen(str);
    printf("%d", k);

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        /*printf("%s", str);
        printf("%c", *str);*/
        printf("%d", i);
        for (j = 0; j < strlen(str) - i; j++) {
            if (str[j] > str[j + 1]) {
                temp = str[j];
                str[j] = str[j + 1];
                str[j + 1] = temp;

            }
        }
    }

    Node *p = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    p->data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(copy));
    p->sig = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(str));

    strcpy(p->sig, str);
    strcpy(p->data, copy);

    p->left = NULL;
    p->right = NULL;
    p->next = NULL;

    Node *rootbackup;

    if ((*root) == NULL) {
        (*root) = p;
    }
    else {
        rootbackup = *root;
        if (strcmp((*root)->data, copy) > 0) {
            sortinsert(&(*root)->left, copy);
        }
        else
        {
            if (strcmp((*root)->data,copy) < 0)
                sortinsert(&(*root)->right, copy);
        }
        *root = rootbackup;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. `p->data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(copy));` 1) You should not cast the return value of `malloc`. 2) To store a string you need `strlen+1` characters.

Comment: `if (str[j] > str[j + 1])` For `i == 0` you access your array behind the last character: `if (str[j] > str[j + 1])` This means you swap the terminating `'\0'`byte moving towards the start of the string. In the next iteration the limit `strlen(str)` will be shorter and shorter....

Comment: I suggest start using a debugger and step through your program.

Answer (score 1):

The loop actually starts if the string size is greater than 0. Yet there is an undefined behaviour because you should allocate memory for the terminating 0:

```
p->data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(copy)+1);
p->sig = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(str)+1);
```

Here is the reported issue without the "+1" in the malloc:

https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/0b30573d